# Why isn't import list working in GHC?

Tags: haskell

The following fails to compile:

```
module Main where
  import Text.JSON (JSObject, JSValue)

  main = print "hello world"
  getObject :: JSValue -> JSObject JSValue
  getObject (JSObject x) = x
```

Giving the error:

```
Not in scope: data constructor `JSObject'
```

But removing the import list allows it compilation to success succeed (even though `JSObject` was imported above)

```
module Main where
  import Text.JSON

  main = print "hello world"
  getObject :: JSValue -> JSObject JSValue
  getObject (JSObject x) = x
```

Why is GHC (7.4.2) ignoring my import of `JSObject`?

Comment: It is not idiomatic to indent after a module declaration, so if you are not particularly attached I would recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you write `import Text.JSON (JSObject)` you only import type, not the constructors it has. To import constructurs do `import Text.JSON (JSObject(..))` or instead of `..` specify comma-separated list of constructor names you wish to use, e.g. `Text.JSON(JSObject(Cons1, Cons2))`